# Custom div on marker mouseover google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a google map using data from the json array with multiple lat and lang of different location. map is created successfully. Now i want to display a custom popup (div with dynamic info) over each marker on mouse over. I tried below code but x,y location return on mouseover are not correct. they are showing same position on different marker hover

```
    var secheltLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lang);

        myMapOptions = { 
     zoom: 13,
    center: secheltLoc,
    scaleControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    icon: 'images/mpicon.png', 
    zoomControlOptions: {position: 
    google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER},mapTypeControlOptions: { 
   mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']} 
},
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("js_bigMap"), myMapOptions);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, draggable: true,position:  new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lang),visible: true,icon: 'images/mpicon.png',});

        marker.setMap(map);

/*markerData contains latlang of locations*/
    for(var i = 0 ; i < markerData.length; i++) 
    {
            marker_ico = 'images/mpicon.png';
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, draggable: true,position: markerData[i].latLng,visible: true,icon: marker_ico,});

            overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
            overlay.draw = function () {};
            overlay.setMap(map);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e)
            {
                var point = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getPosition()); 
                console.log(point);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (e) 
            {
               var point = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getPosition()); 
               console.log(point);
            });
    }/*loop*/
```

Comment: you are using `position: markerData[i].latLng` for all markers. from where are you getting `latLng`?

Comment: latlng are correct. i have already save them in markerData variable. map is successfully created

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue along with a clear explanation of the issue (i.e. the values you are getting for that example and what you expect them to be)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) in your loop to get different values of x,y for different markers

```
(function(marker, overlay) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
        var point = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getPosition()); 
        console.log(point);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (e) {
        var point = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getPosition()); 
        console.log(point);
    });
})(marker, overlay);
```

Hope this helps!